# Add DrawerLayout to TabLayout with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I currently have a ViewPager using a TabLayout. I am dynamically adding elements to the TabLayout based on how many pages the ViewPager has.

I would like to add a DrawerLayout with a burger icon to the left of the TabLayout. This burger icon should stay visible when scrolling the TabLayout.

I tried to add the DrawerLayout beside the TabLayout using a parent RelativeLayout without any success.

**Here is what I would like to do:**

[image]

Here is the current XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/navList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
                    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/drawer_layout"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    ...
    ...
    ...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.app.chasebank"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="#ef453e"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#ef453e"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
      app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listDrawer"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="right"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:background="#FF0000"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am also working on the same task and here is what I have done.